# UI Testing tools for BlackBerry

Tags: testing, blackberry, gui-testing

Is there any UI Testing tools that work on the BlackBerry platform? 
Here's what I know on the subject:

1. There are a few tools that provide unit testing facilities like J2MEUnit (ported), B-Unit, RIMUnit
2. There is an EventInjector API that allows you to inject custom UI events
3. BlackBerry Simulator has an ability to consume scripted commands through FledgeController application. This provides an ability to issue a few categories of events to the simulator: network coverage, gps coordinated, peripherals plugs, specific input events like trackball roll/click etc

Still, I haven't found a working solution that gives you an opportunity to automate UI Testing of BlackBerry applications. The application we're working on has a lot of brands and even smoke/sanity testing requires a lot of manual effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learned that JamoSolutions provides a tool called *M-Eux Test*. They do [support](http://www.jamosolutions.com/documents/blackberry.html) BlackBerry platfom. Basically, you can script your interations with standard GUI elements from BlackBerry SDK along with initiating various device events like baterry level, sms and others.

Comment: BTW, DeviceAnywhere also supports scripting automation. Unfortunately it cannot script UI.